# string index out of range whilst filtering through a list

Tags: python, string, indexing

I keep getting a string index out of range error whenever I tell me code that a character is the fourth in a word, any ideas on why and how to fix it ?

```
with open('/Users/dan/Desktop/wordlist 2.txt') as w:
    wordlist = w.read()
green = lambda letter, place: [x for x in wordlist if x[place - 1] == letter]
grey = lambda letter,: [word for word in wordlist if not any(map(lambda x: x in word, letter))]
yellow = lambda letter, place: [word for word in wordlist if letter in word and word[place - 1] != letter]
count = 0
while True:
    count = count + 1
    if count == 6:
        print(wordlist,'if you have found your word press q')
        q = input(':')
        if q.lower == 'q':
            break
        else:
            count = 0
    result = input('''what was the result of your letter? 
please write the colour
- green = g
- yellow = y
- grey = gr
answer: ''')
    if result.lower() == 'g':
        letter = input('what is the letter: ')
        place = int(input('what place is the letter: '))
        green(letter,place)
    if result.lower() == 'gr':
        letter = input('what is the letter: ')
        grey(letter)
    if result.lower() == 'y':
        letter = input('what is the letter: ')
        place = int(input('what place is the letter: '))
        yellow(letter,place)
```

Comment: How long is the word? You can't access the 4th letter in the word if there are only 3 letters.

Comment: Please read [mre] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and try to trace through the execution of the code. Remove functionality that isn't needed to cause the problem, and hard-code simple input that causes the problem. Then carefully study what the code actually does in that circumstance. You may find it useful to unroll list comprehensions into the equivalent `for` loop. In any event, please actually just `def`ine functions - writing a `lambda` just so that it can be immediately assigned to a variable, gives no benefit beyond saving a few characters of typing.

Comment: @Barmar the wordlist is only 5 letter words, thats why I am a bit confused.

Comment: Make sure there aren't any blank lines in the file.

Comment: `wordlist` isn't a list of words. It's a string containing the entire contents of the file. When you iterate over it, `word` is a single character, not a word.

Comment: It should be `wordlist = w.read().split()` to get a list of words.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed is that wordlist is not a list but just a string. You don't mention the format of the file.

- `file.read()` this method reads all the lines and returns them as a
  single string.

If your file has one word per line then you should this.

- `file.readlines()` this method reads all the lines of
  the text file and returns them as list of strings.

If your file has words separated by spaces then use Barmar's suggestion:

- `wordlist = w.read().split()`

Strings can be iterated so it can be confusing.

Also it is not clear what your program is trying to do so it is not easy to help you.